# Html form checkbox undefined behavior

Tags: html, c, cgi

I have the html code below:

```
<html>
<head><title>OPTIONS</title></head>
<body>
    <p>Choose schedule to generate:</p>
    <form action='cgi-bin/mp1b.cgi'>
    <input type=checkbox name='tfield' value=on />Teacher<input type=text name=teacher value=""/><br>
    <input type=checkbox name='sfield' value=on />Subject<input type=text name=subject value=""/><br>
    <input type=checkbox name='rfield' value=on />Room<input type=text name=room value=""/><br>
    <input type=submit value="Generate Schedule"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is: Whenever I type in one of those text spaces and use my C CGI script to parse it, it gives me the right output which. But whenever I checked one of the checkboxes, it seems to delete the string inputted in the text space corresponding to it. For example, when I check `name='tfield'` and write a string to the text `name=teacher` , it doesn't give me the output for the `name=teacher`. What could be the possible problem in this one? Thanks!

EDITED: Below is the CGI code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *data;
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html><body>");
    data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    char teacher[1024] = "";
    char subject[1024] = "";
    char room[1024] = "";
    sscanf(data,"teacher=%[^&]&subject=%[^&]&room=%s",teacher,subject,room);    
    puts(teacher);
    puts(subject);
    puts(room);
    printf("</body></html>");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to post to C CGI program, else we can not help you.

Comment: @Jori already inserted the code.

Comment: Are you sure the query string data is formatted like that when you click a checkbox? I mean, if the data starts with `"tfield=on&..."` it would fail, wouldn't it.

Comment: Also I wonder who the people are who believe questions about CGI are off topic.

Comment: @MrLister Yes. I have this situation: If I left the three of them unchecked and I put something on each of the three textboxes, all of them will appear. But when I leave the first textbox empty and the two latter textboxes with something, it doesn't give me any output.

Comment: Yes, that is because the query string only contains the inputs that have some value. If you only check all the checkboxes and don't type anything in the textboxes, the query string will be `tfield=on&rfield=on&sfield=on` and will be unparsable by your routine.

Comment: No sir. If I don't type anything on the textboxes but checked all of the three checkboxes, the query string will be `tfield=on&teacher=&sfield=on&subject=&rfield=on&room=` . The name of the textboxes are still passed even if they don't contain any value.

Comment: The string `"tfield=on&teacher=&sfield=on&subject=&rfield=on&room="` fails to match the `sscanf` format `"teacher=%[^&]&subject=%[^&]&room=%s"` at the second character (expecting `'e'`, got `'f'`). `sscanf` stops there and returns 0, which you didn't check the return value (naughty!) so you didn't know it failed.